# Cловосочетание «мало пригодный»

Tags: слитно-раздельно, наречия

Вопрос по наречию. Допускается ли написание *мало пригодно* раздельно? В школе учили, что если можно в сложносочиненном слове составные поменять местами, то пишется раздельно. Притом мало или много, по-моему, смысл не меняется. Скажите, пожалуйста, является ли ошибкой раздельное написание «мало пригодный» — для жизни, например. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Словарь фиксирует наличие в языке прилагательного ***малопригодный***, которое можно отнести к группе **терминов**.

Такие слова образуются **сращением наречия и прилагательного**, но в некоторых случаях  они могут распадаться на исходные составляющие (в частности под влиянием зависимых слов).

**Примечание.** Обратим внимание **на разное ударение** в сложном слове (одно основное ударение) и словосочетании (два ударения). Форма написания в данном случае соотносится с произношением.

**МАЛОПРИГОДНЫЙ**, Недостаточно пригодный для чего-л. М-ая земля для строительства дач. М. для рыбоводства водоём.

Как видно из словаря, это слово **пишется слитно и при наличии зависимого слова**, но на выбор раздельной формы могут повлиять **частные факторы**, например:

(1) Глаз ― **очень мало пригодный** прибор для спектрального анализа света. [С. И. Вавилов. Глаз и солнце. О свете, солнце и зрении (1941)]

(2)  Владимира послали с расчетом, чтобы слава победы осталась за представителем княжеского рода, хотя это был человек **мало пригодный** для подобных предприятий...  [А. П. Ладинский. Анна Ярославна ― королева Франции (1960)]

**Очень мало пригодный**: влияние наречия степени ***очень*** (очень мало).

**Человек мало пригодный**: логическое ударение на слове ***мало***. Кроме того, **термин по отношению к человеку** применять не очень корректно.

**Примечание**

1) Форма написания (слитно или раздельно) не влияет **на семантику этого**  выражения: в обоих случаях (малопригодный или мало пригодный) это будет именно ***недостаточно пригодный для чего-л.***

2) С другой стороны, **термин уместен не во всех ситуациях**.

Сравним: Территория превратилась в малопригОдный для жизни район (**район классифицируется как   малопригодный)**. ― Арктика ― это мАло пригОдный для жизни район (говорится о том, что район труден для жизни).

Answer (score 2):

Оба варианта допустимы, но имеют разные значения. Например, **в мало пригодных для жизни условиях** выжить будет сложно, а **в малопригодных для жизни условиях** — практически невозможно.

При подготовке ответа были использованы материалы пособия: Кайдалова А.И., Калинина И.К.. Современная русская орфография: Учеб, пособие для вузов по спец. «Журналистика».— 4-е изд., испр. и доп.— М.: Высш. шк.,1983. 240 с. 1983

С подробным материалом по словообразованию с **мало-** в этой книге можно ознакомиться [здесь](http://scicenter.online/grafika-orfografiya-fonetika-scicenter/pravopisanie-slojnyih-prilagatelnyih-138506.html).

**Дополнение.**

Приведу выдержку из этого пособия:

> Таким образом, если **мало** имеет значение ‘*не*’, то оно пишется слитно с прилагательным или причастием, которое следует за ним. Если же **мало** выражает значение ‘*немного, недостаточно*’, то оно является наречием и пишется отдельно. Сформулированное правило требует некоторых уточнений.

Далее следует несколько уточнений с большим количеством примеров и разбором наиболее типичных ошибок.

Comment: Попался такой учебный источник: http://www.compendium.su/rus/practical/12.html Здесь прилагательные с мало- и много- рекомендовано писать _слитно_. Внешне похожий случай сочетания наречия "мало" с причастием: при логическом ударении на наречии допускается писать раздельно. Приведён малоубедительный пример: _это мАло исследованная область_ (лучше _мало исследовавшаяся_). В нашем случае - типичное **прилагательное** (не причастная форма), поэтому возможность раздельного написания вызывает большие сомнения.

Comment: Пример _малопригодного для жизни_ из учебника биологии (в книгах часто встречается): https://books.google.ru/books/content?id=jQJFDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA427&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&ots=IMDbm2bSIX&sig=ACfU3U3daiGoJg-qToNZqJBbTDpwaD-TNw&w=1280

Comment: @Alex_ander Я отредактировал ответ — добавил ссылку на источник, которым я пользовался. А *мАло исследованная* вовсе не то же самое, что *мало исследовавшаяся* — разве это не очевидно? За пример из книги спасибо — он подтверждает часть моего ответа. Примеров с раздельным написание в книгах тоже много, если Вы обратили внимание. (Можно задать поиск в гугло-книгах "мало пригодный для жизни".)

Comment: У Розенталя говорится о свободном словосочетании (при наличии зависимых слов) "наречие и прилагательное или причастие", но любопытно, что абсолютно все примеры - с _причастием_("мало исследованные наукой" и др.). http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/30.htm

Comment: @Alex_ander А Вы посмотрите по моей ссылке (в ответе) — там есть многочисленные примеры, в том числе из литературы, а также разбор наиболее часто встречающихся явных ошибок в печати.

Comment: Любопытна статистика поиска по "книгам гугла" (т. е. материалам, прошедшим корректуру). На запрос "малопригодный для" даётся примерно 35 страниц релевантных результатов (написание слитное, изредка проскакивает раздельное), а на "мало пригодный для" подавляющее большинство результатов (при 20 страницах) - с краткой формой прилагательного ("**мало пригодны** для" -  я тоже нормально воспринимаю наречие мало в сочетании с краткой формой), либо с формой "мало-мальски пригодный".

Comment: Видимо, наречие "мало" с полной формой прилагательного (во всяком случае, "пригодный") всё-таки плохо сочетается. Краткое же "пригоден" (ср. "подходит") имеет глагольные оттенки (легко входит в состав сказуемого) и близко по смыслу к причастиям "(мало)- подходящий для".

Answer (score 0):

У меня такое ощущение, что ваш вопрос не совсем верно поняли.
Во-первых, вопрос о **наречии** (мало)пригодно, а не о прилагательном. Так?!
Во-вторых, очень трудно адекватно что-то обсуждать без контекста.
В-третьих, я сильно затрудняюсь придумать нетривиальное осмысленное предложение, в которым (мало)пригодно было бы именно **наречием**. Поэтому, на мой взгляд, что-то обосновывать на примерах соответствующих прилагательных тут не очень корректно. Стилистика употребления наречий и прилагательных может быть разной.

Но попробую. Думаю, что ни вы, ни кто либо еще, не сомневается в том, что раздельное написание не противоречит орфографии и грамматике. То есть вопрос уходит в стилистическую плоскость, насколько такое актуально в разных контекстах.

В Интернете встречают единичные конструкции тира "Это он пригодно сделал". Можно не сомневаться, что тут "пригодно" используется в роли наречия. Поэтому и "малопригодно" здесь выглядит возможным. Но что, простите, вообще будет означать конструкция "мало пригодно сделал"? Я просто не вижу смысла в таком оформлении. *Так что, скорее всего, **раздельное написание будет стилистической ошибкой** - даже в рамках разговорного стиля.*

Если же говорить о прилагательном, то совершенно оправданным считаю использование раздельного написания как минимум в предикативных конструкциях. 
Такое написание меняет если не смысл, то интонацию.

**Мясо было мало пригодно к употреблению.** - здесь акцент на "мало".
**Мясо было малопригодно к употреблению.** - это нейтральное высказывание.

Примеры специально искать не буду, их в других ответах полно.

Comment: В тексте вопроса есть и *мало пригодно* и *мало пригодный*. Скорее всего, автор вопроса не видит разницы.

Comment: @М_Г Очевидно, что вопрос задан о наречии "мало". Я не понимаю, как можно было прийти к альтернативному мнению.

Comment: @grizzly,  "Скажите, пожалуйста, является ли ошибкой раздельное написание «мало пригодный» — для жизни, например", — это о наречии?!

Comment: @М_Г Конечно. О раздельном написании наречия "мало" с прилагательным "пригодный". В учебнике, на который я ссылаюсь, именно так этот вопрос и ставится (в частности).

Comment: @grizzly, А я думал, с наречием *пригодно*. И Мимоходов, кажется, тоже так понял.

Comment: @М_Г - я вообще-то остался в сомнениях, про наречие спрашивают или про прилагательное, но поскольку с прилагательным там и обсуждать особо нечего, то выбрал для себя более интересный вариант. *Скорее всего, автор вопроса не видит разницы* - или считает (ошибочно) возможным автоматически выводить правила одного через правила для другого. Не угадаешь, пока автор сам не сознается.